# In python tkinter , picture's position is changed on running the code again and again

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I write the code in python using tkinter library , in which i used a picture , whose position is not being fixed , it is changed on running the program again and again.
Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter.messagebox
import random


LIST=['HE', 'GO', 'ON', 'IN', 'DO', 'ME', 'SO', 'AS']
answer='GO'

def change_of_word():
    global answer
    answer=random.choice(LIST)

ROUND=1
chances=4

def incriment():
    global ROUND
    ROUND+=1


back=Tk()
def wow():

    def click(x):
        if x in answer:
            global chances;
            if answer[0]==x:
                edit_label_1['text']=x;
            elif answer[1]==x:
                edit_label_2['text']=x;
        else:
    #        if chances!=0:
            label05['text']='Chances left = '+str(chances-1)
            chances=chances-1
            if chances<0:
                frame01.destroy()
                frame02.destroy()
                frame03.destroy()
                keyboard.destroy()
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Looser', 'You have lost, start new game')
                def new_game_start():
                    None
        #if edit_label_1['text']==str(answer[0]) and edit_label_1['text']==str(answer[1]):
        if edit_label_1['text']==answer[0] and edit_label_2['text']==answer[1]:
            if ROUND<5:
                incriment()
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('oh yes!', 'Keep it up buddy!')
                change_of_word()
                frame01.destroy()
                frame02.destroy()
                frame03.destroy()
                keyboard.destroy()
                wow() 
            else:
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Congratulations', "You have completed level 1. Click 'OK' to go to next level")
                frame01.destroy()
                frame02.destroy()
                frame03.destroy()
                keyboard.destroy()
                #wow() function of new level 

    print(answer)
    back.geometry('900x900')
    back.configure(background='#FFFFFF')

    frame01=Frame(back)

    label03=Label(frame01, text='LEVEL 1', font=('arial','35'))
    label03.grid(row=1, column=2,  padx=(250,210) ,  pady=(30,30))

    label04=Label(frame01, text='Round '+str(ROUND), font=('arial','13'))
    label04.grid(pady=(40,40) , padx=(20,20) ,row=1, column=1)

    label05=Label(frame01, text='Chances left = '+str(chances), font=('arial','13'))
    label05.grid(pady=(40,40) ,padx=(3,150), row=1, column=3)

    frame01.pack(side=TOP)


    frame03=Frame(back)
    frame03.configure(background='#142d39')
    label06=Label(frame03, bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', text='Guess a word that contains only 2 alphabets', font=('arial','13'))
    label06.pack(pady=(3,3))
    frame03.pack(fill=X)


    keyboard=Frame(back)
    keyboard.configure(background='#FFFFFF')
    line1=Frame(keyboard)
    btn0001=Button(line1, text='Q',  bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('Q'))
    btn0001.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0001.bind('<a>', lambda: click('Q'))
    btn0002=Button(line1, text='W', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda:click('W'))
    btn0002.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0003=Button(line1, text='E', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('E'))
    btn0003.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0004=Button(line1, text='R', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('R'))
    btn0004.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0005=Button(line1, text='T',  bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF',height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('T'))
    btn0005.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0006=Button(line1, text='Y', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('Y'))
    btn0006.grid(row=1, column=6, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0007=Button(line1, text='U',  bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF',height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('U'))
    btn0007.grid(row=1, column=7, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0009=Button(line1, text='I',  bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF',height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('I'))
    btn0009.grid(row=1, column=8, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0010=Button(line1, text='O', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('O'))
    btn0010.grid(row=1, column=9, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0031=Button(line1, text='P', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('P'))
    btn0031.grid(row=1, column=10, padx=(3,3) )
    #btn0010.bind('<Button-1>', letter_o)
    line1.pack(pady=(1,2))

    line2=Frame(keyboard)
    btn0011=Button(line2, text='A',  bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF',height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('A'))
    btn0011.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0012=Button(line2, text='S', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('S'))
    btn0012.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0013=Button(line2, text='D', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('D'))
    btn0013.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0014=Button(line2, text='F', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('F'))
    btn0014.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0015=Button(line2, text='G', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('G'))
    btn0015.grid(row=1, column=6, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0016=Button(line2, text='H', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('H'))
    btn0016.grid(row=1, column=7, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0017=Button(line2, text='J',  bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF',height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('J'))
    btn0017.grid(row=1, column=8, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0018=Button(line2, text='K', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('K'))
    btn0018.grid(row=1, column=9, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0019=Button(line2, text='L', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('L'))
    btn0019.grid(row=1, column=10, padx=(3,3) )
    line2.pack(pady=(1,2))

    line3=Frame(keyboard)
    btn0020=Button(line3, text='Z', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('Z'))
    btn0020.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0021=Button(line3, text='X', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('X'))
    btn0021.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0022=Button(line3, text='C', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('C'))
    btn0022.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0023=Button(line3, text='V',  bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF',height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('V'))
    btn0023.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0024=Button(line3, text='B', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('B'))
    btn0024.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0025=Button(line3, text='N',  bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF',height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('N'))
    btn0025.grid(row=1, column=6, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0026=Button(line3, text='M', bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF', height=2, width=5, font=('','15'), command=lambda: click('M'))
    btn0026.grid(row=1, column=7, padx=(3,3) )
    btn0027=Button(line3, text=':)',  bg='#142d39', fg='#FFFFFF',height=2, width=5, font=('','15'))
    btn0027.grid(row=1, column=8, padx=(3,3) )
    line3.pack(pady=(1,2))



    keyboard.pack(pady=(0,60), side=BOTTOM)


    frame02=Frame(back)

    frame02.configure(background='#FFFFFF')
    sub_frame02=Frame(frame02, height=1,  width=100, bg='#000000').grid(row=1, column=1)

    global edit_label_1
    global edit_label_2
    edit_label_1=Label(frame02, text='' , height=4, fg='#000000',background='#999999', width=8)
    edit_label_1.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(30,5))
    edit_label_2=Label(frame02, text='', background='#999999',height=4, fg='#000000', width=8)
    edit_label_2.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=(5,30))


    sub_frame02=Frame(frame02, height=1,  width=100, bg='#000000').grid(row=1, column=4)

    frame02.pack(pady=(10,10), side=BOTTOM)




    frame05=Frame(back)

    pic_stage1=PhotoImage(file='stg1.png')
    pic_label=Label(back, background='#FFFFFF', image=pic_stage1)
    pic_label.pack()

    img = tk.PhotoImage(file='stg1.png')
    panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)

    frame05.pack()


wow()





back.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've posted what seems like a lot of unrelated code. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve]. We don't need your whole program, we only need just enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: yeah but i have added a comment

Comment: That doesn't matter. We shouldn't have to wade through hundreds of lines of code to try to find your error. As a general rule, if you're asking someone to help you for free then you should do everything you can to make that as easy as possible for them to help.

Comment: Sorryy bro , I am new , Nex time , i will do as same as you are guiding ,